# How to alert the user if the query is successful in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to alert the user if the query or updating of the database is successful or not..

adduser.php

```
<?php
include('sqlconnection.php');

$firstname = $_POST['fname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lname'];
$middlename = $_POST['mname'];
$password = $_POST['pword'];
$username = $_POST['uname'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$utype = $_POST['utype'];

$query = "INSERT INTO user (firstname,lastname,middlename,gender) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$middlename','$gender')";   

mysql_query($query);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE firstname = '$firstname'");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts (u_id,username,password,utype) VALUES ('$row["id"]','$username',md5('$password'),$utype);")
?>
```

how would I alert the user?or what should I use to give the user a pop-up message saying its successful?

Comment: Just a sidenote, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections, and `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You may wish to read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: @user2062950 thanks..is it better to use mysqli_?

Comment: Yes, but PDO works too. There's an [Overview of the MySQL PHP drivers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) that provides good info on them.

Comment: @jmjassy27 The important part is that you use prepared/parameterized queries.  You need to fundamentally separate the data from the command to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Check number of affected rows, reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php.

Also `mysql_*` functions are depreciated, try using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a variable to mysql_query, for example:

```
 $result = mysql_query("your query");

 if($result){
 $xxx = "query successful";
 }else{
 $xxx = "query failed";
 }
```

In the hmtl:

```
 <script>
 alert(<?php echo $xxx;?>);
 </script>
```

This is one way, from here you can play to do whatever you want

---

As side Note: Mysql_* extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

A useful link [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` returns false for invalid query. `mysql_num_rows()` returns number of records returned for query like select. `mysql_affected_rows()` checks for affected rows.

**EG:**

```
$result = mysql_query("your query");

if($result){ 
  //query successful but this doesn't mean it returned anything
  //you can now use mysql_num_rows (for select query) to check if something is returned
  if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
   //some results were returned
  }

  //for insert, update or delete query you need to check affected rows like this
  if( mysql_affected_rows() > 0 ){
   //some records were updated or deleted
  }
}else {
  echo "There was a problem";
}
```

Sidenote: `MySQL_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Use `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead.